# How to remove the footer in compare product print page in magento2

Tags: magento2.3, php-7.2

Currently, Our compare product print page showing the footer section on that.

I want to remove the footer link in compare product print page.

How to do that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Compare Products Page footer link is getting rendered from the below layout XML file. Copy the below file from the vendor path to your current theme.

vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_compare_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
        <action method="setPageTitle">
            <argument translate="true" name="page_title" xsi:type="string">Compare Products</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Compare\ListCompare" name="catalog.compare.list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/compare/list.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

Add the below lines to remove the footer section

```
    <referenceContainer name="footer-container" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="copyright" remove="true" />
```

The Final Version should look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
        <action method="setPageTitle">
            <argument translate="true" name="page_title" xsi:type="string">Compare Products</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Compare\ListCompare" name="catalog.compare.list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/compare/list.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceContainer name="footer-container" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="copyright" remove="true" />
</body>
</page>
```